# Access to local file with javascript in UWP webview

Tags: javascript, c#, webview, win-universal-app, openlayers-3

i'm trying to run javascript OpenLayers in UWP(C#) app in webview. And I need to read the local .osm file.

The start of JS code is:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Vector({
                source: new ol.source.Vector({
                    url: 'example.osm',
                    format: new ol.format.OSMXML(),
```

in the line with url: 'example.osm' I set the source of .osm file.

The code worked in Firefox, but in Edge or Chrome didn't. So I think the same problem will be with UWP webview and Edge.

Is there any way how to do it?

Comment: What does the console say? Are you running a webserver or from a file? I know chrome has issues loading files if it's not served by a webserver

Comment: Yes, you are right, Chrome's console says that it doesn't support file:// protocol (just http:// ...). And I need to use it in webview but the app has to work offline. So I am not runnig a webserver.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [electron](http://electron.atom.io/)(unaffiliated, never used) or some other product that build webapps into desktop. Might fit your use case

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load local files using the file:// protocol since it would be a risk to allow javascript to load arbitrary things off of your file system. You will have to run it from a webserver.

If this is just for your personal use you can install a webserver on your local machine. A lightweight easy install webserver I recommend [Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb). Otherwise the usual suspects should be sufficient (apache,node,IIS,etc...)

If you need to distribute the application to other people I would look into products that bundle web applications into desktop applications. I'm not expert in this space but one such product is [electron](http://electron.atom.io/)

Comment: I was afraid of it. Cause the app is written in c# and I just need this part of the app with javascript OpenLayers for vector maps. So I think I'll need to find another way.

Comment: Since it's in C# you could implement a webserver to serve the page https://codehosting.net/blog/BlogEngine/post/Simple-C-Web-Server.aspx